# after create CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, profile status not changing from pending to active in paypal

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions, paypal

I am working with Paypal recurring payment.
Paypal recurring profile will creating successfully, but initial payment will not made. and profile status will not changing even i checked it after a day.

See this screenshot of my  Paypal account [sc1](http://awesomescreenshot.com/08555nsy34), [sc2](http://awesomescreenshot.com/05255nszc3)

I think issue is not with php code. is there any other settings that i need to do? even my IPN not working because payment is not completed by Paypal.I am using Paypal express checkout api.

Comment: are you using REST api?

Comment: yes express checkout

Comment: @NiteshVirani you have any idea? regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you create recurring plan it is in CREATED state, you need to update it by calling update service and make it ACTIVE

As per the [PayPal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#billing-plans-and-agreements), you have to explicitly update the status by calling it again.

Comment: but i am using [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) API, there is no function to update profile status. only update the content and price using `ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus`. first same code will working greate, issue is sometime it will working but sometime not working. also status is in `pending` case.it will set to `active` after paypal made payment

Comment: @himanshuarchirayan PayPal provides the many variants of API to integrate, the API you are using should have similar process to update the status.

Comment: API which i am using is activate profile automatically there is no manual process to set profile `active`. by default status is `pending`, when charge will cut status will change to `active`. so in this case we cant handle it by coding. also this functionality working for me some days before, but after some days this happening.